# Using Transport Layer while still using NetworkManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a Unity networked project for which I am using the very convenient Unity Networking High Level API (with Network Manager component and Network Discovery among other components). This projects runs fine on two Android phones over LAN.

I need now to transfer a big byte array (3 to 10 MB) from server to clients before the client actually loads the Online scene. For that purpose I took inspiration of this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGkkaNkq8co on the transport layer API but it is not as simple as I expected as now my client phone doesn't load the online scene even if I am sure that the hosts and the clients are actually exchanging messages. I put logs everywhere, and the last message that I have is

> Async DNS Result:10.11.85.190 for 10.11.85.190: 10.11.85.190

which is called by NetworkClient.cs

I don't post my code because that would be too much to read and actually instead of trying to fix something that looks now like the bad way of doing it, my question is:

Do you guys know the correct way of using the Transport Layer API  **AND** the High Level API (basically a NetworkManger component for managing connections) **at the same time** ?

or

Do you know how can I send this big byte array on reliable channel just before the online scene is loaded?

Thanks for any hints.